# How to upload multiple seperate folders and thier contents to a single zip file to JFrog Artifactory using "jf rt upload". ( /Alpha, /Beta, /Gamma)

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

Given the following folder structure:"/Alpha,/Beta,/Gamma,/Delta, ..."

Using JFrog CLI how can I upload only the first two folders and thier entire contents.

Ive tried the following using a regular expression:

`jf rt upload "Alpha|Beta" My-generic-local/My-rep-folder/target.zip --archive zip --dry-run --regexp`

[Error]CreateFile Aplha|Beta: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You can try File Specs for this purpose.

```
jf rt upload --spec=filespec.json
```

filespec.json:

```
{
  "files": [
    {
      "pattern": "Alpha/",
      "target": "My-generic-local/My-rep-folder/target.zip",
      "archive": "zip"
    },
    {
      "pattern": "Beta/",
      "target": "My-generic-local/My-rep-folder/target.zip",
      "archive": "zip"
    }
  ]
}
```

Learn more about JFrog File Specs:

1. [JFrog File Specs](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Using+File+Specs)
2. [Using File Specs in JFrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-UsingFileSpecs)